# Zend Framework 2 - How to give declare folder path in terms of "use" and "namespace"

Tags: zend-framework2

I am facing problem while creating adapter object in controller file named Listcontroller.My code is

```
namespace Blog\Controller;
use Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class ListController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
    * @var \Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface
    */
    protected $postService;

    public function __construct(PostServiceInterface $postService)
    {
        $this->postService = $postService;
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);
        print_r($adapter);
        //code ....
    }
}
```

here it is serching to find Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter inside Blog\Controller.
Error is -> Fatal error: Class 'Blog\Controller\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' not found. Can anybody tell me please how can i move two folder back from above path. so that i can get proper object??

Comment: have you tried this  -> (Blog\Service\PostServiceInterface\PostServiceInterface $postService)

Comment: No, because it is PostServiceInterface object i want to fetch data inside controller using adapter object given documentation as                          

                $sql = new Sql($adapter);
  $select = $sql->select();
  $select->from('post');
  $select->where(array('id' => 2));

  $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
  $results = $statement->execute();

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the fully qualified class name (FQCN) when instantiating a new `Adapter` since you declare that class path via use statement:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
```

Change this block

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray);
    print_r($adapter);
}
```

to

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $adapter = new Adapter($configArray);
    print_r($adapter);
}
```

It should work.

Anyway, `new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($configArray)` also works (notice the first backslash) but its longer, harder to type and less readable than first example.

You may also want to read [namespace aliasing/importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) section of the documentation.

Comment: Ok, i had made changes as per your suggestion, Thank you for ans, it's working properly. And thanks for documentation reference.